# Getting pyqt application focus for popup menu to disappear when clicking away from it

Tags: menu, focus, pyqt

Let me quickly explain the background to this. I'm developing a custom menu system inside a 3D application called Softimage XSI. It has a PyQt application object created already and ProcessEvents is being called a certain number of times every second so that PyQt applications can exist in a non-modal state within XSI.

To implement the menu, I've got a webpage embedded in a toolbar which is calling a plugin for XSI that I've written to show a PyQt menu. This all works fine (albeit, slightly contrived!).

The issue is that when I show the menu, it won't disappear when I click away from it. If I move the mouse over the menu, and *then* click away from it, it *will* disappear. It's only when it first pops up.

I've tried everything I can think of. Here's a list:

- Using **QtGui.qApp.installEventFilter(menu)** to try and catch the mousepressed signal. It never gets triggered. I suspect the application itself isn't receiving the click.
- Using **menu.raise_()** makes no difference
- Neither does **QtGui.qApp.setActiveWindow(menu)**
- Or **menu.setFocus()**
- I've also tried:

  ```
  event = QtGui.QMouseEvent(QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove, pos, QtCore.Qt.NoButton, QtCore.Qt.NoButton, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
  QtGui.qApp.sendEvent(menu, event)
  ```
- I had a go writing my own QEventLoop, but it just crashed XSI. I suspect trying to run a modal loop inside the other one probably isn't a legal thing to do. Either that, or I really don't know what I'm doing (equally probable)

The only thing I have partial success with is using *grabMouse()*. This is what makes the menu close if I click away from the menu (only *after* the mouse has passed over the menu once), but I have to call it a couple of times for it to "stick".

So this is my code at the moment:

```
class MyMenu (QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grabbed=2

    def getMouse(self):
        if self.grabbed>0:
            self.grabMouse()

        self.grabbed-=1

    def paintEvent(self, event):       
        QtGui.QMenu.paintEvent(self, event)    
        self.getMouse()

    def hideEvent(self, event):
        self.releaseMouse()   


def ShowMenu():
    menu = MyMenu()
    menu.addAction("A")
    menu.addAction("B")
    menu.addAction("C")

    submenu = MyMenu()
    submenu.addAction("D")
    submenu.addAction("E")
    submenu.addAction("F")
    menu.addMenu(submenu)
    menu.setTearOffEnabled(True)

    menu.setStyleSheet("font: 8pt \"Sans Serif\";")
    submenu.setStyleSheet("font: 8pt \"Sans Serif\";")
    submenu.setTitle("Window")
    submenu.setTearOffEnabled(True)

    pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
    pos.setX(105)

    menu.popup(pos)

    #Prevent garbage collection
    QtGui.XSIMenu=menu
    QtGui.XSISubMenu=submenu

    #Desperate acts!    
    menu.raise_()
    QtGui.qApp.setActiveWindow(menu)
    menu.setFocus()
```

Any thoughts or random suggestions would be very gratefully received as this is driving me nuts! Don't be afraid to suggest modifications to stuff I've already tried, as I'm relatively new to PyQt and I may well have missed something.

Many thanks,
Andy

Comment: I have a similar problem.  What did you do to solve this?  Oddly, grabMouse provided the same partial success, but is clearly not the correct approach.

Comment: I never did unfortunately. Would love to hear if you ever find a way around it.

Comment: just figured it out.  just before I call to popup the system tray menu with self.trayMenu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos()), I call self.trayMenu.activateWindow().  Putting activateWindow before popup makes the left-click menu work the same as the right-click menu and it goes away when you click elsewhere. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before calling popup with self.trayMenu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos()), call self.trayMenu.activateWindow(). Putting activateWindow before popup makes the left-click menu work the same as the right-click menu and it goes away when you click elsewhere. :)